# Search for partial character string in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, find-and-replace

The search tool in Excel allows for the string to be either a part of the cell or the entire cell, but can I use it for more complex options? For example, if I'm looking for cells ending in "cht", to count them I would use "*cht" with COUNTIF. How can I use the same option for searching?

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do? Search for `cht` in a cell? If it exists then ...?  Are you looking for it *anywhere* in a cell? You could just use `"*cht*"` with `COUNTIF()`.

Comment: I'm looking for an easy way to see **what** cells end in `cht`, not just count them.

Comment: Do none of the answers posted here work for you?

Answer (score 1):

I use free [RegEx Find / Replace add-in](http://www.codedawn.com/excel-add-ins.php), that adds search functionality to Excel.

To look for cells ending in `cht` simply use the expression: `cht$` (`$` marks end of cell)

*(I'm not affiliated with that add-in in any way, just an enthusiast user.)*

Comment: I've also used this add-in, and it has worked very well for me.

Comment: Looks cool but the page reports incompabilities with 64-bit version of Excel 2010 and that's exactly my version. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

One relatively easy and quick way is to use a helper column to detect if the cell ends in `cht`, then filter on that:

In `B1`: `=IF(COUNTIF(A1,"*cht"),CELL("address",A1),"")`

Then filter out:
[image]

Edit: **OR** - if you used the helper column like above, you can use this (entered with <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd>) in say `D2`and drag down:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$100,SMALL(IF($B$2:$B$100<>"",ROW($B$2:$B$100)-ROW(B$2)+1),ROWS(B$2:B2))),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Remember OP has written, "**For example, if I'm looking for cells ending in "cht", to count them I would use "*cht" with COUNTIF. How can I use the same option for searching**", *and your solution does't Counts!!*. Check the above written comment by Bruce he has also suggested to Count.

Comment: @RajeshS  - look at OPs comment under the post. They're looking for a way to see *what cells, end in "cht". Is that not what I'm doing, regardless of the formula used?

Comment: @Rajesh, if you read all the comments, OP is saying he knows how to *count* the cells (he would use  COUNTIF), but he wants to *find* the cells. Batman's answer is completely valid.  You should be very cautious about criticizing an answer, considering how tenuous your grasp of the language is and thus your understanding of the question.

Answer (score -1):

If you search for *cht using the "Find..." menu choice, then Excel will find cells which contain cht at the beginning, middle or end of the text in the cells. Excel can also find cht in the formulas.

But if you click the checkbox for "Match the entire cell contents" in the Find dialogue box, Excel will find only those cells which end with "cht". For example, "Sample**cht**" or "I'm**cht**". It will not find cells which have "cht" in other locations like, "This is **cht**sample" or "**cht**temp".